# What's wrong with this rewrite rule?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have this `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^!/(.*)$ path/to/a/file/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ path/to/another/file/$1 [L]
```

I want urls in the form of `www.website.com/!/this/` to be rewritten to `path/to/a/file`. Any URL that doesn't match that pattern should be rewritten to `path/to/another/file/`.

Here's what I've tried to far:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^!/(.*)$ path/to/a/file/$1 [L]
RewriteCond ...
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ path/to/another/file/$1 [L]
```

When using the above rewrite rule, I get a 500 - Internal Error.

How can I fix it?

Comment: @BookOfZeus, http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteCond

Comment: IIRC ! is not a valid URI character.  This will cause mod_rewrite to barf on this pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/!
RewriteRule ^!/([a-z0-9_\-\.]+) user/public/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/!
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_\-\.]+)/([a-z0-9_\-\.]+)/?$ $1/controller/front.php/$2 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/!
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_\-]+)/([a-z0-9_\-]+)/([a-z0-9_\-]+)/?$ $1/controller/front.php/$2/$3 [L]
```

Comment: I didn't know it was an example, I based my answer on your question. Before I updated my answer can you please tell me what is the rule for the `path/to...` if it's dynamic can you give me examples? Thanks

Comment: Now I get a 404. Also I have to specify `to/public/` and `controller/front.php/` as relative to the path that contains the `.htaccess` not to the root (`RewriteBase /`).

Comment: Can you please give me more examples, so you can have: /file/to/public/ and /folder/folder/to/public/ and same for the controller/front.php/?

Comment: I simply don't know the real path. I don't know where could my application be put in. Yes. It could be everywhere. I just want that when a request get to `.htaccess` should process the URI from there on like it is said in `.htaccess`. So if `.htaccess` is in `/sample/`, `/sample/this/` should be considered as `/sample/controller/front.php/this/`.

Comment: so what about: `/sample/this/another` or just `/sample` or `/sample/this/folder/another/`?

Comment: Anything after sample/ that is not a file in `sample/user/public/` should be redirected to `sample/controller/front.php/`. (let's just lose the `/!/` part...)

Comment: ok thanks for the example, i'm getting closer but one more question, can you give me some examples of `/!/`, i want to make sure i got it right thanks

Comment: `/!/` should be converted to `sample/user/public/` which, as said before, should be public accessible. And if the main `sample/` folder is inside another (such as `another/sample/`), `<img src="!/image.png"/>` should still redirected to `another/sample/user/public/image.png`. So I guess we should look for relative paths, not absolute paths.

Comment: if the image is `!/image.png` how can you know it's in `another/sample/` and not `this/sample`?

Comment: You can't. What we are sure of it that the folder that has the `.htaccess` will be `another/sample/` or `this/sample/` or whatever it is. So the `.htaccess` is always in the folder that also contains `user/`. So if we have `another/sample/.htaccess` we will also have `another/sample/user/public/image.png`. If we have `this/sample/.htaccess`, we will also have `this/sample/user/public/image.png`.

Comment: you can have multiple .htaccess?